# How to create a mp4 video out of Octave/via plot

Tags: octave

This is a follow up to question 54847941. I make videos from sequences of images created by Octave using the print command, for example:

```
clear;
for kt=1:100
  t(kt)=0.1*kt;
  clf,plot(t,sin(t),'linewidth',1);axis([0,10,-1,1]);
  fname=strcat('img',num2str(kt,"%0.2i"),'.png');
  eval(['print -dpng ' fname ' -r100']);
endfor

##use ffmpeg to make mp4 with:
##ffmpeg -framerate 20 -i img%02d.png -vf scale=1080:-1 Example1.mp4
```

This works when the imgaes are small, but if they are large, the print operations takes a very long time.  What is an alternative to my method, using functions like getframe and imwrite?

Comment: Probably not the main bottleneck, but there's absolutely no need for an 'eval' statement in that code. You can use the functional form of print to pass `fname` instead. Typically eval statements do not benefit from any optimisations. Secondly, you can probably save some time by updating the plot's ydata instead of clearing the figure and creating a new plot object every time. Having said that, presumably the main overhead is printing images like you said, in which case, if the video package doesn't work for you, consider exporting the data to python/opencv in some common format (e.g. hd5) etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your initial code took 15.5s on my machine. The first optimization step is to keep the plot and update xdata and y data:

```
t = linspace (0, 10, 100);
for k = 1:numel(t) 

  y = sin (t(1:k));

  if (k == 1)
    p = plot (t(1:k), y, 'linewidth', 1);
    axis ([0, 10, -1, 1]);
  else
    set (p, "xdata", t(1:k));
    set (p, "ydata", y);
  endif
  fname = sprintf ("img%03i.png", k);
  print ("-dpng", "-r100", fname);
endfor
```

This takes 13.1s on my machine. Next we can use getframe:

```
out_dir = "temp_img";
mkdir (out_dir);
t = linspace (0, 10, 100);
for k = 1:numel(t) 
  y = sin (t(1:k));
  if (k == 1)
    p = plot (t(1:k), y, 'linewidth', 1);
    axis ([0, 10, -1, 1]);
  else
    set (p, "xdata", t(1:k));
    set (p, "ydata", y);
  endif
  fname = fullfile (out_dir, sprintf ("img%03i.png", k));
  imwrite (getframe (gcf).cdata, fname);
endfor
cmd = sprintf ("ffmpeg -framerate 20 -i ./%s/img%%03i.png -vf scale=1080:-1 Example1.mp4", out_dir)
system (cmd)
```

This takes 3.7s even with running ffmpeg .

Keep in mind that if you're creating images (I guess like your vortex videos) you haven't go though plot

Comment: Correct, I can create the image through imagesc. followed by setting gca'ydir' to 'normal'.  I suppose I can call imwrite immediately after. I hadn't thought that I could use system to include the ffmpeg command inside my octave script.  Can octave do that part directly (without calling ffmpeg)?

Comment: @ClintonWinant There is a video package which gives you aviread/write so you can directly add frames but you don't have that fine control (for example setting crf). Another possibility is to use the OpenCV bindings for Octave which brings cv.VideoWriter but at the end I think calling ffmpeg gives you the most flexibility

Answer (score 0):

While I really appreciate Andy's anwser, his ffmpeg command did not work for me. I had to replace the `%03i` with `%03d` because ffmpeg 6.1.1 under Windows didn't recognize the 'i' as a legitimate format specifier.

So, if you're like me, you'll need:

```
cmd = sprintf ("ffmpeg -framerate 20 -i ./%s/img%%03d.png -vf scale=1080:-1 Example1.mp4", out_dir)
```

Comment: The suggestion in the meta help is make edits. Sadly, edits must be at least 6 characters... so I've suggesed a less-optimal edit than I would normally make. There does not seem to be any good path here.

Comment: I think what you've done here is okay. please avoid writing meta commentary out of answer posts. I've edited it out.